# Data structure for many-many

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

What  data structure is suited for representing and handling a many-to-many correspondence.
I need to handle matching of 2 facing streams of messages;where an entity in one stream can match to multiple in the other stream and vice-versa.
Inserts  and retrievals will not be frequent but an evaluation of whether an entity is present in the domain('contains') of data will be quite frequent.
I am particularly interested in python - but i guess it applies equally to any programming language.
Any pointers in the correct direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have two sets, a and b.  Elements in a map to elements in b, and vice versa.

You can use a graph-like data structure (adjacency list)

```
# this maps elements in a to elements in b (elements of a are the keys)
# each element of a maps to several elements of b (as a list)
a2b = {
       'a' : [1,2,3]
      }

# this maps elements in b to elements in a (elements of b are the keys)
# each element of bmaps to several elements of a (as a list)
b2a = {
        1 : ['a'],
        2 : ['a'],
        3 : ['a'],
      }
```

You basically have a dictionary of lists.  'a' maps to 1,2,3 in the left to right direction, and 1,2,3 all map to 'a' in the other direction (in this example).  You can map an element to any number of other elements, and vice versa.

To find the domains, you can use the keys of the dictionary.  In the above example, you can do this:

```
>>> print 1 in b2a
True
>>> print 'a' in b2a
False
```

To check if `elem` is in your domain (in following example, if `elem` is in set b), you just do

```
elem in b2a
```

Checking if an element is inside of a set is pretty fast, which is what you want.